# Page loads over the previous page in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `$stateprovider` to navigate between pages I had given `$state.go('view1')` to go to view1.html:

```
config(['$qProvider','$stateProvider','$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($qProvider,$stateProvider,$locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
   $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'index.html'
        })
        .state('view1', {
            url: '/view1',
            templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
            controller:'View1Ctrl'
        })
        .state('view2', {
            url: '/view2',
            templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html'
        });
   $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
   $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
 }])
```

Function using `$state`:

```
 controller("appcontroller",['$scope','$state','$stateParams',function($scope,$state,$stateParams,$rootScope){
$scope.login = function()
{
    $state.go('view1');

}
}]);
```

Here view1.html is loading but it's showing above index.html.

Comment: can you share inde.html?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Anguar ui-router. You must have kept  in index.html. So your view1.html will be replaced there only. Other code in index.html will be untouched by your angular code.

```
<p> Here is me </p>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Now, if you change the route. "Here is me" will be always there.

Hope this was the issue what i understood.

Comment: I've tried as u told, but now its not going to the second page.

Comment: can you share html fille?

Comment: Sorry the previous issue is gone. Now when the second page loads it shows twice. The content is loading twice.